# Functions not showing up in Azure Function App

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-functions

I am migrating my functions to V2 from V1 which were running previously. I removed the V1 init.py and function.json files in favor of the V2 function_app.py however when I pushed to github the functions will not longer show up in my functions app despite GH deploying successfully. The functions are on timer triggers and I suspect that it has something to do with the configuration of the host file. I have tried many configurations without any progress. Below are the details of my app and host file. The file folder structure is as follows:

(python_file(n) are files referenced in the function_app.py file)

```
- monitoring_weekly (folder)
   - function_app.py
   - python_file1.py
   - python_file2.py
   - python_file3.py
   - python_file4.py
   - python_file5.py
- host.json
- local.settings.json
```

host file

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensionBundle": {
      "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
      "version": "[4.0.0, 5.0.0)"
    },
    "extensions": {
      "timer": {
        "maxConcurrentExecutions": 1,
        "scheduleStatusFilePath": "app_offline.htm"
      }
    }
  }
```

function app file

```
import azure.functions as func
import os
import datetime
import logging
import sys
import importlib.util

# Azure function timer. To alter timer cadence see function.json file
app = func.FunctionApp()

@app.function_name(name="monitoring_weekly")
@app.schedule(schedule="0 5 * * MON", 
              arg_name="mytimer",
              run_on_startup=False,
              use_monitor=True) 

def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest) -> None:
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()
    
    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')
        
    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)


def run_script(script_name):
    script_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), f'{script_name}')

    s = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(script_name, script_path)
    m = importlib.util.module_from_spec(s)
    sys.modules[s.name] = m
    s.loader.exec_module(m)

    
def batch_execution(file_list):

    exceptions = [] #store errors

    for file in file_list:
        try:
            run_script(file)
        except Exception as e:
            exceptions.append(e)
        else: 
            print('Success')

    return exceptions

#list of scripts running in function, if adding new script add to list.
file_list = ['python_file1.py',
        'python_file2.py',
        'python_file3.py',
        'python_file4.py',
        'python_file5.py']

batch_execution(file_list)
```

Runtime stack = Python 3.10
Runtime version = 4.24.4.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your requirement in my requirement in my environment with your `function_app.py` code and I could see the **function trigger** in **Azure function app** after successful deployment.

**My Project Structure:**

```py
- _pycache_
- .python_packages
- .vscode
- env
- .funcignore
- .gitignore
- function_app.py
- host.json
- local.settings.json
- python_file1.py
- python_file2.py
- python_file3.py
- python_file4.py
- python_file5.py
- requirements.txt
```

**host.json**

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}
```

**Local Response:**

[image]

- Created **Python Function app** in Azure Portal
- Application Settings of my Function App:
  Make sure you have the below settings in your function app.

[image]

- Deployed the Python function project to **Function app** through **GitHub**:

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**Deployed function application files:**

[image]

**Response:**

[image]